# Print statement is executed thrice, while execution only runs once

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code works just fine in terms of what I want it to print, but somehow it prints fs three times. So instead of for exampling printing A just once, it prints A tree times, each on a separate line. Why?

```
sr = input("Enter score: ")
for i in (sr):
    try:
        fs = float(sr)
        if fs > 1.0: print("decimal only")
        elif fs >= 0.9: print("A")
        elif fs >= 0.8: print("B")
        elif fs >= 0.7: print("C")
        elif fs >= 0.6: print("D")
        elif fs < 0.6: print("F")
    except:
        print("Bad score")
        sr = input("Enter score: ")
        continue
```

If user input is for example 0.8, it should just print B.

Comment: Because you are running this in a loop over the individual characters of the `sr` input. First `i` is `'0'`, then `i` is set to `'.'`, then to `'8'`. You never use `i` in the loop, so you don't see this happen.

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are not processing user input, therefore when you for loop over a string, you loop over the letters one by one therefore one for each ".08", You should process your input by first splitting by spaces (if you are expecting multiple inputs separated by spaces) and cast them to an integer.

It is not clear why you want to for loop over your input, if you are expecting a single input there is no need, if you want multiple inputs you must decide if you want them all input before processing or one at a time ( which would require a while loop).

```
sr = input("Enter score: ")
sr = sr.split(' ')

for i in (sr):
    i = int(i)
    try:
        fs = float(sr)
        if fs > 1.0: print("decimal only")
        elif fs >= 0.9: print("A")
        elif fs >= 0.8: print("B")
        elif fs >= 0.7: print("C")
        elif fs >= 0.6: print("D")
        elif fs < 0.6: print("F")
    except:
        print("Bad score")
        sr = input("Enter score: ")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a for-loop unless you want the program to run continuously after evaluating the user input. If you do then just adding a while-loop would work.

```
while True:
    try:
        sr = input("Enter score: ")
        fs = float(sr)
        if fs > 1.0: print("decimal only")
        elif fs >= 0.9: print("A")
        elif fs >= 0.8: print("B")
        elif fs >= 0.7: print("C")
        elif fs >= 0.6: print("D")
        elif fs < 0.6: print("F")
    except:
        print("Bad score")
        sr = input("Enter score: ")
```

Comment: Your `else` would never be reached; either `float` raises an exception, or it returns a valid floating-point value that is guaranteed to make one of the next six conditions true.

Comment: Oops, I didn't add the try-except. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Why are u typing : -
    for i in (sr): #

This will lead to loopind till ur digits example for 0.8 - three times for 0.88 - Four times for 0.888 - Five times instead do this kind of stuffs.

```
sr = input("Enter score: ")
if sr>=0 :
    try:
        fs = float(sr)
        if fs > 1.0: print("decimal only")
        elif fs >= 0.9: print("A")
        elif fs >= 0.8: print("B")
        elif fs >= 0.7: print("C")
        elif fs >= 0.6: print("D")
        elif fs < 0.6: print("F")
    except:
        print("Bad score")
        sr = input("Enter score: ")
        continue
```